# How to iterate over a list of lists and print items of each list as a comma-delimited string

Tags: python, list

If I have a list of lists:

```
x = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]
```

How do I iterate over these lists and print them to get the following output?

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
for l in x:
    print ', '.join(map(str, l))
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 5):

You pretty much have it:

```
# python
x = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]

for i in x:
  print i[0]
1
4
7

for i in x:
  print i
['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
['7', '8', '9']

for i in x[0]:
  print i
1
2
3
```

Comment: erm its not exactly what im looking for. When I print I wish to print each list how it is for example the above code would print 1,4 and 7 but i wish to print 1,2,3

Comment: the second one does print [1,2,3]. if you only want to go through the first one, i'll add that in a sec.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

for i in chain.from_iterable(x):
    print i
```

Comment: I know this answer is 8 years old but this is the best way to do it in my opinion and helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about processing each element in the arrays one-by-one (I'm assuming here that the printing is just an example and your your actual desired processing is more complicated), the *simplest* way is to not do that. You obviously have your data structured in that way for a reason, in which case your code should mirror it.

You save *very* little by doing that with a single `for` statement so I would use:

```
for xlist in x:
    for n in xlist:
        do something with n
```

Believe it or not, having your code mirror your data actually improves code readability.

As an example, to get your exact output as specified in the edit:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

x = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]

for xlist in x:
    s = ""
    for n in xlist:
        s = "%s, %c"%(s,n)
    print s[2:]
```

Comment: +1 for "Believe it or not, having your code mirror your data actually improves code readability."

Answer (score 0):

Just for the concept, the actual traversal is very simple:

```
for i in x: #a list
    for j in i: #elements of the list
        print j
```

This will print 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, every number in a newline

You can change the pattern as you would want.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]

[k for y in x for k in y]
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```